# I want to to get multiple images from the url and have to use them in my image view

Tags: android, image, url, bitmap

My application crashes on execution i have used bitmap `array` for storing images .can anyone help me out special thanks in advance not providing the url but i am using the valid url of images so there is not a problem.

thank you.

```
    package abc.expandable;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static final String URL =
                " some url";
        public static final String URL1="some url";
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageView imageView1;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray=new ArrayList<Bitmap>(4);
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
            GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            // Execute the task
            int a=0;
            task.execute(new String[]{URL});
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(0));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "downloading image please wait ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           // task.execute(new String[]{URL1});
            //imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(a));
        }

        private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                Bitmap map = null;
                for (String url : urls) {
                    map = downloadImage(url);
                }
                return map;
            }

            // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
            {

    //            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(0));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("bitmap", "bitmap ");
            }

            // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
            private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                InputStream stream = null;
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

                try {
                    stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                            decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
                return bitmap;

            }

            // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
            private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                    throws IOException {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConnection.connect();

                    if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return stream;
            }

        }
    }
```

here is the log cat

```
03-04 18:59:24.307 18588-18588/abc.expandable E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: abc.expandable, PID: 18588
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{abc.expandable/abc.expandable.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                    at abc.expandable.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Why are you not using any Image library like Picasso or Universal Imageloader Or Glide libary to load the images

Comment: i just have few images so i want to get them on my own without using any library

Comment: Are you want to save those images in sd card

Comment: Better make use of a library like Glide, takes care of a lot of stuff for you

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: how can i add the image into array using picaso

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and it should work:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(0));
```

You are accessing an empty array and this causes the exception because your array members are added in a different thread that is slower than your UI thread. You should set your imageview in the onPostExecute of you ASyncTask. This way, you make sure that the ASyncTask has finished and has added members to your array before you try to access them.

Comment: so how will i set the image to the imageview if ill remove this

Comment: I already explained, do it in the onPostExecute. You have even already commented out that line in your code.